# strange php behaviour with numbers

Tags: php

I am running this code snippet in php.

```
for ($zip=01001;$zip<99950;$zip++){
// DO WORK WITH MYSQL
    sleep(0.04);    
    echo $zip;
}
```

To my surprise 513 is the first number that gets echoed, 514 the second and so on. What is going on here?

Comment: You're working with octals (and decimals). Get rid of the leading zero (01001)

Comment: Zips aren't integers (if you are talking about zip codes).

Comment: A number beginning with `0` in PHP (like `01001`) is treated as an Octal value...... [exactly as the PHP Documentation says](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.syntax).... `1001` octal is `513` decimal

Comment: how do you prepend the zeros? The zero must be present when I do stuff on $zip. Just put the parenthesis around?

Comment: If you need to prepend zeroes, you do it on display only, and using [sprint()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or [str_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

Comment: Actually I am not going to print it. Many websites request zip code. if zip code does not contain 5 digits, it is invalid. So when I submit the zip, it must be a 5 digit number. As you can see the problem arises with zips lower than 10000.

Comment: If you aren't going to print it why `echo $zip;`? What is your actual usage. Zips aren't integers and shouldn't be treated as such.

Comment: $zip will be submitted to a form. if zip code does not contain 5 digits, it is invalid. So when I submit the zip, it must be a 5 digit number.

Comment: Submit it as a string; zip codes (like telephone numbers) aren't actually numbers

Comment: Okay, so use http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php or `/^\d{5}$/`. Then make sure DB has non-integer data type.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a zero-padded string:

```
for ($zip=1001; $zip<99950; $zip++){
    $zip = sprintf("%05d", $zip);
    // $zip is now a string ranging from "01001" to "99949"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using strings and right before posting to form check

```
if (strlen($zip)<5){
    $zip5Digits = "0"."$zip";
}
```